# Implicit declaration of getpid in kernel code even though I included unistd.h

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I'm currently working on a project that includes using PIDs. When I compile my program in a linux VM, I get the following message:

```
kernel/sys.c:2405: error: implicit declaration of function ‘getpid’
kernel/sys.c:2407: error: implicit declaration of function ‘getpriority’
```

even though I have included:

```
#include <asm/unistd.h>
```

in my code.

I have also tried to use `types.h`, but that does not work either.

Here is a snippet of the erroneous code, if it might help:

```
if(new_process != NULL){
            pid = getpid(new_process->p);
            pid2 = getpid(sem->head);
            p = new_process->p;
            if(getpriority(which, pid) > getpriority(which, pid2)){
                new_process->next = p;
                sem->head = p;
```

Any suggestions are welcome, and thanks for your help.

Comment: `<asm/unistd.h>` is not the right header. Try `<unistd.h>`.

Comment: @n. 'pronouns'm. Hello. ```<asm/unistd.h>``` was included by default in my sys.c file, and that is where it lies in the directory. It states that it cannot find the file if i only do ```#include <unisdt.h>```

Comment: Are you compiling a kernel module? `in a linux vm` - what linux vm is that and how did you created it?

Comment: @kamilcuk I am compiling on my university's supercomputer, using make ARCH=i386 bzImage

Comment: You are compiling a piece of Linux kernel code. Linux kernel code doesn't have anything from `unistd.h` available. `getpid` doesn't take parameters anyway, so you are doing something very wrong.

Answer (score 3):

As I understand, you're working with kernel code. There's no C standard library in the kernel! You don't have `getpid()`, `getpriority()`, or any other standard library function or header (some very common functions like `strlen()` are re-defined in the kernel, but not all of them). To achieve what you want, you'll have to use the appropriate equivalent kernel APIs, which are usually more low level.

Assuming that `new_process->p` and `sem->head` are [`struct task_struct`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/sched.h#L629), you can get their priority with the [`task_nice()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/sched.h#L1612) function defined in `linux/sched.h` (which is exactly what the `getpriority` syscall does, if you take a look at [the code](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/sys.c#L281)).

Your snippet could be then re-written like this:

```
if(new_process != NULL) {
    p = new_process->p;
    if(task_nice(p) > task_nice(sem->head)) {
        new_process->next = p;
        sem->head = p;
```

If for some reason you also need the PID, you can access it directly through `p->pid`, as it is a field of `struct task_struct`.